# UWP/WinRT: How to move a button when the window is resized into a new position?

Tags: responsive-design, windows-runtime, uwp

My app opens documents in tabs, and at the top of each tab similar to a web browser, I have a row of `Buttons` in a `StackPanel` for functions to affect the document. As these `Buttons` deal with and belong to each document, they are  generated dynamically from a binding along with the document.

I'd like to make my app more responsive so that when the window size drops below a certain width, to save space these buttons are moved into a `Flyout` and restyled as appropriate.

Edge browser does something like this with the Hub, Web Note, and Share buttons.

How can I do this? Is it possible just by using `AdaptiveTriggers`? Or would this be done through the code behind?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with code behind you can handle

```
page_SizeChanged
```

Then check for the bound with

```
if ((Window.Current.Bounds.Width < YOUR_WIDTH) || (Window.Current.Bounds.Height< YOUR_HEIGHT))
  {
    // change Visibility or Move items
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the behaviour you are looking for on small screens is an off-canvas menu, then here's one way you could do this.

There are plenty of off-canvas extensions, one that would work well for you is [mmenu](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl)

Play with this to get a feel for how to configure it. It will provide the sliding behaviour you are looking for.

Mmenu will always collapse the menu, so the final step is to modify its behaviour so that it only collapses on narrow viewports, and one way to do this would be to toggle the class name that's wrapping your menu. For example if your menu is

```
<nav class="my-menu">
....
</nav>
```

then inside a jQuery document ready statement you could do something like the following

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
 if ($(window).width() >= 900){
    $('.my-menu').addClass('my-menu-off').removeClass('my-menu');
 } else {
    $('.my-menu-off').addClass('my-menu').removeClass('my-menu-off');
}

}).trigger('resize');
```

When the viewport is 900px or wider this will remove the .my-menu class, and so your menu won't collapse. If the screen is < 900px mmenu will do its magic.

I think approach would be a good because it will be easy to adapt to your existing HTML. You'll just need to add jQuery if it's not already included in your project, and the mmenu js and css files.

Good luck!